# How to show Image in Slider in Laravel?

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, slider

I have some images stored in database, And i want to show those images in slider view, But images and coming in random format, they are not coming in slider one by one, Please help me for this, How i can show all images in slider...

here are my code where images are showing...

```
<div id="carousel-thumb" class="carousel slide carousel-fade carousel-thumbnails list-gallery pt-2" data-ride="carousel">
                                        <!--Slides-->
                                         @forelse($prop->proImage as $sliderimage)
                                        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                                <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{asset('property_img/'. $sliderimage->large_thumb_url.'/'. $sliderimage->large_thumb)}}" alt="slide">
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                        @empty
                                          @endforelse
                                        <!--Controls starts-->
                                        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-thumb" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                            <span class="lnr lnr-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-thumb" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                            <span class="lnr lnr-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                        </a>
                                        <!--Controls ends-->
                                        <ol class="carousel-indicators  list-gallery-thumb">
                                            <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="0"><img class="img-fluid d-block w-100" src="{{asset('images/fp-1.jpg')}}" alt="..."></li>
                                            <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="1" class=""><img class="img-fluid d-block w-100" src="{{asset('images/fp-1.jpg')}}" alt="..."></li>
                                            <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="2" class=""><img class="img-fluid d-block w-100" src="{{asset('images/fp-1.jpg')}}" alt="..."></li>
                                            <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="3" class=""><img class="img-fluid d-block w-100" src="{{asset('images/fp-1.jpg')}}" alt="..."></li>
                                            <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="4" class=""><img class="img-fluid d-block w-100" src="{{asset('images/fp-1.jpg')}}" alt="..."></li>
                                            <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="5" class=""><img class="img-fluid d-block w-100" src="{{asset('images/fp-1.jpg')}}" alt="..."></li>
                                            <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="6" class="active"><img class="img-fluid d-block w-100" src="{{asset('images/fp-1.jpg')}}" alt="..."></li>
                                            <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="7"><img class="img-fluid d-block w-100" src="{{asset('images/fp-1.jpg')}}" alt="..."></li>
                                        </ol>
                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--Slides-->
   @foreach($resultSet as $record)
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
             <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{asset('property_img/'. $record->large_thumb_url.'/'. $records->large_thumb)}}" alt="slide">
          </div>
        </div>

   @endforeach
   <!--Controls starts-->
   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-thumb" role="button" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="lnr lnr-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-thumb" role="button" data-slide="next">
     <span class="lnr lnr-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
 <!--Controls ends-->

 <ol class="carousel-indicators  list-gallery-thumb">

    @foreach($resultSet as $record)

     <li data-target="#carousel-thumb" data-slide-to="{{ record->id }}" class=""><img class="img-fluid d-block w-100" src="{{asset('images/fp-1.jpg')}}" alt="..."></li>
    @endforeach; 
 </ol>
```